# java servlet. redirect to static page do not work

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet, who should initially redirect to static html page (example.html)

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws IOException{

            response.sendRedirect("/example.html");
        }

}
```

But it not works, because on redirect it's again request servlet instead of static page, then redirect, etc.

Why it always asking for servlet, and what should I change to make it simply redirect to my `example.html` page.

App hosted on Tomcat 7

UPD1: Mapping looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.web.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you give us the servlet mapping definition from your web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this lines to your `web.xml` file

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The reason why it's not work currently, because you configure only single mapping for your requests, and then they handled by your servlet. Adding this mapping you told to your app that you want to handle html file in different (default) manner.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to amed the `web.xml`. Instead give the correct URL for the `sendRedirect` function argument. Remember the `sendRedirect` function will trigger a fresh request.